# ImageMagick で画像に「背景色が正円の文字」を追加したい

Tags: 画像, imagemagick

やりたいこと
ImageMagick で画像に「背景色が正円の文字」を追加したい。

Q1.画像に下記のような「背景色が正円の文字」を追加合成できますか？
上の数字は1から12までのいずれかの表示で、
下の大きな数字には1から31までのいずれかの数字を想定

[image: 例1]

---

Q2.画像に下記のような「背景色が正円の 1 桁か 2 桁の文字」を合成できますか？
数字には1から31までのいずれかひとつを想定

[image: 例2]

円を描画するにはcircleメソッドを使用すればよいと思うのですが、その前面に文字を描画するには、pointsizeで文字を描画してcompositeするしかないですか？
文字を描画する際、背景色も指定できると思うのですが、この背景色を矩形ではなく正円に指定する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1. 画像に「背景が正円でラベルが日付(上が「月」、下が「日」)」を追加合成できるか？

```bash
# 対象画像の1/2幅($w)と1/2高さ($h)
$ eval $(identify -format 'w=%[fx:int(w/2)] h=%[fx:int(h/2)]' flower.jpg)
# 正円の中心座標($cx, $cy)と半径($r)
$ cx=60 cy=50 r=40
$ convert flower.jpg \
    -draw "translate $cx,$cy fill white circle 0,0 0,$r \
           fill black gravity center \
           font-size 16 text -$w,$(expr -$h - 20) '12' \
           font-size 36 text -$w,$(expr -$h + 10) '18'" \
  Q1.jpg
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> Q2. 画像に「背景が正円でラベルが1桁か2桁の数字」を追加合成できるか？

```bash
$ eval $(identify -format 'w=%[fx:int(w/2)] h=%[fx:int(h/2)]' flower.jpg)
$ cx=60 cy=50 r=40
$ convert flower.jpg \
    -draw "translate $cx,$cy fill white circle 0,0 0,$r \
           fill black gravity center \
           font-size 36 text -$w,-$h '18'" \
  Q2.jpg
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 期待通り完璧に動作しました。「ImageMagickの convert コマンド」だけを使用できると思っていたのですが、シェルスクリプトのevalコマンドなども使用できるのですね。また画像情報を取得できる大変便利なidentifyコマンドがあることも初めて知りました。一行目の「対象画像の1/2幅($w)と1/2高さ($h)」の意味が分からず悩んだのですが、テキスト描画位置を「gravity center」で画像中央に指定しているので、そこからオフセットの基準点となる左上を算出するために使用しているのですね。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 1):

おそらく日替わりのカレンダー的なものを作ろうとしているものと思われますが、「背景が正円の文字」にこだわらず、もっと単純に「背景画像」＋「左上に正円」＋「透過色が透明な文字」の合成では駄目でしょうか。

参考になりそうな記事:
[画像に文字を重ね貼りするコマンドライン処理（ImageMagickでテキストイメージ生成＋合成）](https://qiita.com/myoshimi/items/1e63a4d7c27c01c1701f)

> - ImageMagickだけで，画像に文字を重ね張りする仕組みを作ります
> - 連続した複数の画像の隅に，数字（ページ番号など）を合成します